# uwp camera is closing in certifyed app

Tags: camera, uwp

i have a very strange problem with the camera of Windows phones in my uwp app.
If i execute my code in Release or debug mode, everything went well, but if i builld the appxupload files and submit them to the store, the app is closing if i execute the code.

```
 public async void startcamera()
    {
        CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
        Size aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
        dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
        dialog.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        dialog.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.SmallVga;
        StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
        if (file != null)
        {
           //do stuff
        }

    }
```

The Problem occurs only on Windows Phones (i tryed different devices), if I install the app on a x86 device with a webcam it works fine.

I read something about unsopported resolutions, but as i said, in release or debug mode it works even on the Windows Phone without any problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A quick an easy way to make your app pass the certification would be to wrap the code in `try-catch` which would keep your app from crashing.

On the solutions side, you can modify your code like:

```
internal async void PickFromCamera()
{
   RestartZone:
   try
   {
      CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
      captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
      captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(300, 150);

      StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
      await HandleFileOperationsAndStorage(photo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       var promptResponse = await MessageDialogHelper.ShowTwoActionsMessageBox($"Somehting went wrong while decoding the image from the camera. Please make sure no other operation is being carried out. \nMore Information: {ex.Message}", "Operation Failed", "Try Again", "Cancel");
       if (promptResponse)
           goto RestartZone;
     }
}
```

and it should work just fine.

The message dialog helper is a class I have that handles all message box popups, you can have your own error handling there.

Comment: The code does not cause an exception... The camera starts for a second an then both are closing, the camera ans my app. if i run the code in visual studio on my device, it works perfekt. Buit If i disconnect the device from the Computer and start the app on its own, the behaviour occurs.

Comment: The problem seems to be, that the app is suspended and terminatet when the camera starts. the debugmode seems to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: I Implemented as suspension manager, but it looks like the app is terminated after suspension.

Comment: can you prepare a quick demo project and share it?